# how to give action to UIImageView using the objective-c

Tags: ios

i have used the code:

```
images=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Navarre-Family-Eye-Care-Navarre-Florida-Optometrist-Santa-Christmas-Toy-Safety.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Christmas-Wallpapers-HD-Picture.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Christmas-Wallpaper-jesus-9413550-1024-768.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tree.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"luxury-christmas-napkins-father-christmas-1635-p.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Navarre-Family-Eye-Care-Navarre-Florida-Optometrist-Santa-Christmas-Toy-Safety.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Christmas-Wallpapers-HD-Picture.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Christmas-Wallpaper-jesus-9413550-1024-768.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tree.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"luxury-christmas-napkins-father-christmas-1635-p.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tree.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"luxury-christmas-napkins-father-christmas-1635-p.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Navarre-Family-Eye-Care-Navarre-Florida-Optometrist-Santa-Christmas-Toy-Safety.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Christmas-Wallpapers-HD-Picture.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Christmas-Wallpaper-jesus-9413550-1024-768.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tree.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"luxury-christmas-napkins-father-christmas-1635-p.jpg"], nil];

        // NSString *dd=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", images];
        // NSLog(@"%@",dd);


        if(images== nil ||images.count <5) {
            return; // early return
        }

        NSMutableArray* randomImageArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:5];
        while (randomImageArray.count < 5) {
            UIImage* image;
            do {
                NSUInteger random = (NSUInteger)arc4random_uniform(images.count);
                image = [images objectAtIndex:random];
            } while ([randomImageArray containsObject:image]);
            [randomImageArray addObject:image];
        }
        self.b1.image = [randomImageArray objectAtIndex:0];
        self.b2.image = [randomImageArray objectAtIndex:1];
        self.b3.image = [randomImageArray objectAtIndex:2];
        self.b4.image = [randomImageArray objectAtIndex:3];
        self.b5.image = [randomImageArray objectAtIndex:4];
       // self.b6.image = [randomImageArray objectAtIndex:5];
          [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(pik) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];




        //  self.b4.image = [randomImageArray objectAtIndex:3];
        //  self.b5.image = [randomImageArray objectAtIndex:4];
        // self.b6.image = [randomImageArray objectAtIndex:5];
        //  [self getRandomValueFromArray:images randomDataCount:6];
    }
-(void)pik{

    nnn=[[mem_test alloc]init];

    [self presentViewController:nnn animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

here i got the output .i need to pass the images which is stored in randomImageArray to other UIViewController how to do

and how to give action to the UIImageView?

Comment: Do you mean you need to pass some data to another screen?

Comment: yes,actually i need to pass the images which i got in randomImageArray ,i need to pass this in otherviewcontroller and i need to display this in the uiimageview to the new viewcontroller